# mysql wont take null, instead sets 0

Tags: php, mysql, null

I am trying to insert a NULL value into my DB, I tried different examples but the result kept turning up as 0
so I forced it, note the line below //**************
$gefid = null;
yet is still shows up as 0, have tried with and without quotes, capitals, you name it.
The field definitely allows Nulls and nulls are default
code:

```
<?php

DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'xxxxxxxxx');
DEFINE ('DBPW', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
DEFINE ('DBHOST', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com');
DEFINE ('DBNAME', 'Mydb');


$dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
if (!$dbc) {
die("Database connection failed really badly: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit();
}

$dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
if (!$dbs) {
die("now the dam Database selection bit failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit();
}
$lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['lat']);
$lng = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['lng']);

$prox = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['prox']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['description']);
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['id']);
$direction = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['direction']);
$avoiddays = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['avoiddays']);
$validfrom = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['validfrom']);
$validto = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['validto']);



if (isset($_GET['gefid'])) {
  $gefid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['gefid']);
} else {
  $gefid = null;
}
//***********************************
$gefid = null;
$expiry = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['expiry']);

$query = "INSERT INTO realtime (rt_lat,rt_lng,rt_prox,rt_description,rt_direction,rt_avoiddays,rt_validto,rt_validfrom,rt_gefid,rt_expiry) VALUES ('$lat', '$lng', '$prox', '$description','$direction','$avoiddays','$validto','$validfrom','$gefid','$expiry')"; 

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: try to remove the single quote for `$gefid` in your INSERT INTO statement

Comment: And start using prepared statements.

Comment: Try this, 
if (isset($_GET['gefid']) && !empty($_GET['gefid'])) {

other wise problem in your table schema

Comment: I will use prepared statements in the future, thanks Bart, I have removed the quotes, but now I get error  "for the right syntax to use near ''')' at line 1 on line 43" which is the insert stmt.  However if I manually NULL in the insert stmt  it works and NULL appears in the DB.

Comment: @hopelessbob setting `$gefid` to (PHP) `null` and inserting it, will result in incorrect SQL (`echo` your SQL te be sure). `$gefid` should be `"NULL"` (string) for this to work.

Comment: Thankyou Bart, "NULL" works :) Reading about prepared statements also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. `$gefid = "NULL";` instead of: `$gefid = null;`
2. remove quotes from `$gefid` in `INSERT INTO statement ('$gefid' to $gefid)`

Because `NULL` is a keyword that should be passed to MySQL instead of `"NULL"` which is a string, you are trying to pass a string to integer field in database.

EDIT: But if that is the case you should get MySQL error, double check your Schema for a Default 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `INSERT` statement, not the variable assignment. To insert a `NULL` value, your statement should look like this (note, no quotes around `NULL`):

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (NULL);
```

You could create some extra code to add or leave out these quotes, but I strongly advice to use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), where you don't have to worry about escaping and quotes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Someone commented about the table schema but I will elaborate. 
You need to check if your table definition has default values automatically assigned and also see if the column is not null.

If you use:

```
   SHOW CREATE TABLE realtime;
```

And check the fields for

```
   DEFAULT 0
   NOT NULL
```

If either of those column definitions are present then you wont be able to insert a null value into those columns.

Comment: Looks OK : CREATE TABLE `realtime` (
 `rt_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `rt_lat` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
 `rt_lng` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
 `rt_prox` int(8) NOT NULL,
 `rt_direction` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rt_avoiddays` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rt_validfrom` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `rt_validto` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `rt_gefid` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rt_description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
 `rt_expiry` bigint(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rt_id`),
 KEY `rt_lat` (`rt_lat`,`rt_lng`),
 KEY `rt_lng` (`rt_lng`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8